What should one do if someone abuses one's Guru and Guru's family members?
Kindly quote references which deal with this subject

My Guruji does not need references I do..

@User29449 don't do personal attack. Take this as a warning.

Can you quote scriptural references?

The disciple must never hear Guru Ninda. When someone is abusing or censuring the Guru, the disciple should put his hands on his ears and leave that place. This is mentioned both in Kularnava Tantram and the Manu Smriti.

Manu Smriti 2.200. Wherever (people) justly censure or falsely defame
his teacher, there he must cover his ears or depart thence to another
place.




Yatra sriguruninda syat pidhaya sravaneambike |
sadyastasmadnisvinishkramet punarna shravanam yatha | Gurornama
smaret pashchat shravane sa pratikriya ||
O Ambike! One should not lend his ear to any censure of the Guru.
Where such a criticism occurs one should close his ears, get out from
there and remember the name of the Guru as reaction to it.
Kularnava Tantram 12-80

So not only one should leave the place immediately but as a parayaschitta measure one should also chant the Guru's name or remember the same.
